# JS eventListener clicking problems

Tags: javascript, html, onclicklistener, event-listener

I just need some help with this small header of my project. I decided to include all the header files so you can run it in snippet and check for yourself what is happening. The only thing that I have having problem with is my JS file. If you run the file, you would get a menu bar and a shopping cart on top, I designed them to not open up at the same time hence the if else statements. Now the problem is after the web page loads, I cannot open the menu bar right away no matter how many times I click it. But, if I try to click the shopping cart, it would require two clicks before it drops down and works. But here's the weird part, after the shopping cart has dropped down, the menu bar would now work. After this occurrence, everything works the way they are intended to work. A little help please, I am currently stuck on this one. Thanks!

```js
var showShoppingBtn = document.getElementById('shopping-cart');
var showShopping = document.getElementById('top-dropdown');


showShoppingBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{

    if(showShopping.style.display == 'none' && showMenu.style.display == 'none'){
        showShopping.style.display = 'block';
    } 
    else if(showShopping.style.display == 'none' && showMenu.style.display == 'block'){
        showMenu.style.display = 'none';
        showShopping.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        showShopping.style.display = 'none';
    }
});

var menuBtn = document.getElementById('menu-button');
var showMenu = document.getElementById('bottom-dropdown');

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{

    if(showMenu.style.display == 'none'  && showShopping.style.display == 'none'){
        showMenu.style.display = 'block';
    } else if(showMenu.style.display == 'none' && showShopping.style.display == 'block'){
        showShopping.style.display = 'none';
        showMenu.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        showMenu.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap");

body {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
.top-content{
    background: orange;
    display: flex;
}
.shopping-menu{
    width: 100%;
}
#shopping-cart{
   font-size: 2.5em;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding-right: 0;
   float: right;
   margin-right: 1em;
}
.top ul{
    margin-top: 3em;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
.top li{
    padding-right: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    text-align: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.top-content-container{
    width: 100%;
}
.top-dropdown{
    display: none;
}
.site-logo img{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    display: none;
}
.bottom{
    background-color:#0e1338;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}
.menu{
    padding-right: 1em;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu-button{
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-right: 1em;
}
.bottom-content-container{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 1em;
}
.bottom-content-container ul{
    list-style: none;
}
.menu-bar{
    width: 3em;
    height: .5em;
    background-color: white;
    margin: .5em 0;
}
.bottom-dropdown{
    display: none;
    margin-top: 4em;
    text-align: right;
}
.bottom-dropdown li{
    margin: .7em 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.top li a{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.bottom li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/header.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="top">
      <div class="top-content">
        <nav class="shopping-menu">
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" id="shopping-cart"></i>
        <div class="top-content-container">
              <div class="top-dropdown" id="top-dropdown">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Checkout</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My Purchases</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="bottom">
      <div class="site-logo">
        <img src="images/AutoNation-logo.png" alt="AutoNation Logo">
      </div>
      <nav class="menu">
        <div class="menu-button" id="menu-button">
          <div class="menu-bar"></div>
          <div class="menu-bar"></div>
          <div class="menu-bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-content-container">
          <ul>
            <div class="bottom-dropdown" id="bottom-dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Special Offers</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
            </div>
          </ul>
      </nav>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script src="scripts/header.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because first time you entered the click function both style.display are not filled. so the condition

```
showShopping.style.display == 'none' && showMenu.style.display == 'none'
```

will not be evaluate

one quick solution to use your code is to initialize style.display at the end of the js part

```
showShopping.style.display = 'none';
showMenu.style.display = 'none'
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it for me. I didn't realize that but I tried doing this earlier but decided not to since this project is a reactive media project. This fixed it for me, I just had to specify in JS that the code was for my mobile media query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you do `element.style.someStyle`, you access only the inline style of the element. So the first time you click on `showShoppingBtn` it will pass in the last else -> setting the inline style of it to `display: none`.
A quick fix to that would be to add inline style directly in the html. like so :

```
<div class="top-dropdown" id="top-dropdown" style="display: <The defautl display you want>;">
```

And

```
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" id="shopping-cart" style="display: <The default display you want>;"></i>
```

Comment: Tried this and worked as well. Set them both to display: none and worked fine, but I decided to just declare it in the JS to make it look cleaner

Answer (score 0):

1. Your HTML is invalid
2. You really should toggle a class. Add class hide to the menus and have `.hide {display:none}`

Then you can do

```
showShoppingBtn.addEventListener('click', () => { 
  showMenu.classList.add("hide")
  showShopping.classList.toggle("hide")
});
menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  showShopping.classList.add("hide")
  showMenu.classList.toggle("hide")
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm new to JS that's why haha. But anyway thanks so much for this, I am going to try this out. I haven't been able to try using the classList.add and .toggle yet. But will surely try this one. Thanks again